# Add block device mappings to EC2 with AWS-CDK, python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am getting error while adding 2 block device mappings for ebs volumes.  I am using aws-cdk, python.

Here is the code

```
    from aws_cdk import core
    from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as _ec2

    #Webserver 01
    webserver = _ec2.Instance(
        self,
        "webserver01Id",
        instance_type = _ec2.InstanceType(instance_type_identifier="t2.micro"),
        instance_name = "webserver001",
        machine_image = _amzn_linux_ami,            
        vpc=vpc,
        vpc_subnets = _ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC),
        user_data = _ec2.UserData.custom(_user_data),
        block_devices= {"block_device_mappings": [
            {"device_name ": '/dev/sda1', "volume": _ec2.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(50)}, 
            {"device_name": '/dev/sdm', "volume": _ec2.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(100)}
            ]
        } 
    )
```

Here is the error I am getting.

> ```
> jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected array type, got {"$jsii.map":{"block_device_mappings":[{"$jsii.map":{"device_name ":"/dev/sda1","volume":{"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.BlockDeviceVolume@10012"}}},{"$jsii.map":{"device_name":"/dev/sdm","volume":{"$jsii.byref":"@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.BlockDeviceVolume@10013"}}}]}}
> Subprocess exited with error 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of CDK API [1.63.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Instance.html) for the `aws_ec2.Instance` class states that `block_devices` should be a list of `aws_ec2.BlockDevice` instances [link here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/BlockDevice.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.BlockDevice) rather than a `dict`.

Comment: thanks for your response. On the documentation page [link](https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.aws-ec2/) for the same version of the API (search block device) there is a "block_device_mappings" property.  I believe, I have a syntax issue.